# Automatic update of fields with SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, report, ssrs-2012

I'm currently working on a Java Project to generate the XML of an SSRS Report, without using Report Builder (this project writes the XML of a report to an .rdl file).

I'm stuck on the Datasets part of my project. I provide a query to my Dataset and when I open my report, my Dataset is created but the fields are not displayed.

[image: fields not displayed]

And When I execute my report, I have an error that tells me a problem with my DataSet.

[image: error]

*This error means "An error occured during local report processing".*

The solution I found is to go to "properties of the dataset" and click on "Refresh fields".

[image: Refresh]

*"Actualiser les champs" means "Refresh Fields".*

The list of fields is displayed and I can run my report without any problem.

[image: After refresh]

So I wanted to know if it was possible to have the fields update automatically without going through the properties of the DataSet and without the action of the user ?

I have already tried to edit the "AutoRefresh" value of the report, without success.

Is there an option to make this happen or some way to run the script behind the button ?

P.S : I need to generate a hundred of Dataset, so my click on "refresh fields" of each Dataset is not viable.

Thank you for any help you can give me.

Comment: Are you adding all the **Fields** in the XML or just the query? My guess is that the report builder needs to run that refresh function to generate the Field data.

Comment: This might be a bug. It should refresh the fields when you put in a query and press OK. Regardless, after the fields show up and you save the report, your users should be able to run it fine.

Comment: How about comparing the rdl before and after the "Refresh Fields" to see what the refresh command changed in the file?

Comment: By default fields are automatically refreshed unless there are issues with the sql code execution

Comment: @HannoverFist - Thank you for your answer. I only add the query to avoid writing the XML of the fields parts in the rdl file. Indeed, Report Builder needs to execute the refresh function, so my goal is to execute the refresh function automatically without clicking on it.

Comment: @Lucky - Thank you for your answer. I don't write my query directly into the report builder, so I don't need to press OK. I put my query directly in the rdl file.

Comment: @WolfgangK - Thank you for your answer. I already compared the rdl file before and after the "refresh fields". Before : there is only the query; After : There is the query + the field part that is associated with the SELECT of the query. So my goal is to write the fields part automatically by simulating the click on "refresh fields".

Comment: @niktrs - Thank you for your answer. I put my query directly in the rdl file, so I don't need to press OK.

Comment: @Anthony.G So you already know what to do... but what are you asking for?

Comment: @WolfgangK - I don't my project to write the fields part in the rdl file but I want to simulate clicking on "refresh fields". For example, by doing reverse engineering on the Report Builder software or by modifying an option on Report Builder which would allow to refresh the fields automatically.

Comment: @Anthony.G You said that you are working on a project to create a report automatically. You already seem to be able to create the biggest part of the rdl file. Since you already have got that far, I think that you will also be able to insert the fields part. I suggest to [start here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008/dd297486(v=sql.100)).